# howto play mjpeg udp stream via gstreamer

Tags: stream, udp, gstreamer, mjpeg

I have problem with playing udp mjpeg stream.
e.x.:

```
ffmpeg -i <some video file> -pix_fmt yuvj422p -s 640x360 -r 25 -c:v mjpeg -f mjpeg udp://localhost:2345
```

what works:

```
ffplay udp://localhost:2345
```

what is the gstreamer (gst-launch-1.0) command to play this? I've tried many but no success at all.

Comment: Did you find the command with gstreamer ?

Comment: Still no success.